# Radial tiled clone where objects point to center of rotation in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I'm trying to arrange some shapes radially using **Tiled Clone**. The objects are distributed evenly as I was hoping, but the orientation is not what I'm aiming for. I'd like all the "fish" objects to point towards the center of rotation, rather than chasing each others' tails as is happening now.

[image]

I'm using **ShiftX per Column of -100%** and no other **Shifts**, and **1 row, 8 columns**, with **Rotation** of **45 degrees**.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have 2 opposite faced objects as a group. Make only 4 copies with shift X=-100%, rotate 45 degrees. Delete the original. It's duplicated.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For this specific problem, note that there's also the 'Rotate Copies' Live Path Effect available (Path > Path effects > + > Rotate copies) which allows you to rotate everything by mouse on the canvas.

And then there's also the 'Polar Arrangement' tab in the 'Arrange' dialog (Object > Arrange).

Both of these are easier to use for circular arrangement than the tiled clones for most users.

Answer (score 3):

I came late to the party but somebody might still find this helpful.

If you move the rotation centre of the original shape then you'll change the alignment of the tiled clones. In your case, move the rotation centre below the fish's nose.  Imagine you stuck a pin in your clones before turning them through the rotation angle.
[image: 7 clones around rotation centre]